# how to set command binding For All controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

how to set command binding For controls that are not possible in wpf ?
for exmaple how to set command in listBox items? or how to set command in treeView items?

```
                            <ListBox  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolToggleListBox}"  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}" >
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Kind="MicrosoftWindows" />
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Games" />
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem IsSelected="True">
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Video"  />
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem>
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Image" />
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListBoxItem` doesn't implement `ICommandSource`. That's why it cannot execute `ICommand`. To solve this you can override the template of `ListBoxItem` and use a `Button` as content host:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ListBox>
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Button Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

      <ListBoxItem>
        <materialDesign:PackIcon VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Kind="MicrosoftWindows" />
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

---

If you need to assign individual commands to each item you would need to define an `ListBox.ItemTemplate` with a `Button` as content host which binds `Button.Command` to a `ICommand` property of the data item.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class LabelData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string label;
  public string Label
  {
    get => this.label;
    set
    {
      this.label = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private ICommand myCommand;
  public ICommand MyCommand
  {
    get => this.myCommand;
    set
    {
      this.myCommand = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  // Initialize the data binding source of the ListBoxItems
  public void LabelData(string label)
  {
    this.Label = label;
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<LabelData> labels;
  public ObservableCollection<LabelData> Labels
  {
    get => this.labels;
    set
    {
      this.labels = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  // Initialize the data binding source of the ListBox
  public void ViewModel()
  {
    this.Labels = new ObservableCollection<LabelData>() 
    { 
      new LabelData("MicrosoftWindows") { MyCommand = SomeCommand},
      new LabelData("Games") { MyCommand = SomeOtherCommand},
      new LabelData("Video") { MyCommand = SomeOtherCommand},
      new LabelData("Image") { MyCommand = SomeCommand}
    };
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Labels}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="LabelData">
          <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
            <Button.Content>
              <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Label}" />
            </Button.Content>
          </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Both options apply to a `TreeView` too.
A third option is to use an Attached Property to attach an `ICommand` to each `ListBoxItem` or any other `Control` (basically to any `DependencyObject`).
A fourth option is to create your custom item by extending `ListBoxItem` and implementing `ICommandSource`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean? The Command property is just the "Binding Way" for The Button_Click property.
If you want to have a ListBoxItem where you can click on and Call a Method, then just go with this:

```
    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Button Content="Test"
                        Command="{Binding}">
                </Button>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: yes  i want to have a ListBoxItem where can click on and Call a Method but Your solution is not good because I want to use other controls that are not available

Comment: So that is exactly what I gave you in the Answer.

Comment: no i cant use this code because I created a custom listBox that has a specific icon item and breaks it down with your code

Comment: So please edit your Question, you havent mentioned once that you´ve made a custom listBox. Also please show the Code of the listBox.

Comment: It should still work with this for example:                                                              
             <ListBoxItem IsSelected="True">
                <Button Command="{Binding}"/>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Video"  />
            </ListBoxItem>

Comment: However, it is not a good solution to put the button inside any control that is not Command-specific